# Z order for animation in LinearLayout

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout, z-order

I have an activity with a LinearLayout:
-CustomToolbar
--DynamicallyScaledItems
-ContentFrame (rest of the screen)
--Implemented with changing fragments

When an Item of the CustomToolbar is clicked it grows (also growing the CustomToolbar), and the ContentFrame should animate up behind the CustomToolbar replace the fragment and move down again.

This would be just easy if the Z order of the ContentFrame were behind the CustomToolbar. But I cannot pull the CustomToolbar in front as it would also change the Y order in the LinearLayout.

How can I solve this?

With a RelativeLayout? How would I define that the ContentFrame would always take the rest of the screen below the CustomToolbar?

Thanks,
Mick

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with RelativeLayout and following parameter for the ContentFrame:
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"